# Using Uri.MakeRelativePath and obtaining the correct relative path

Tags: c#, path

If you execute the following lines of code:

```
new System.Uri("C:\\Windows\\System32").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe")).ToString()
```

and

```
new System.Uri("C:\\Windows").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe")).ToString()
```

You get:

```
"System32/Notepad.exe"
```

and

```
"Windows/System32/Notepad.exe"
```

Shouldn't it be `"Notepad.exe"` and `"System32/Notepad.exe"`, respectively? It appears that the final portion of the base path is included in the resulting relative path, which is incorrect, isn't it?

If I do something similar with web Urls:

```
new System.Uri("http://example.com").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("http://example.com/this/is/strange")).ToString()
new System.Uri("http://example.com/this").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("http://example.com/this/is/strange")).ToString()
new System.Uri("http://example.com/this/is").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("http://example.com/this/is/strange")).ToString()
```

I get results as follows:

```
"this/is/strange"
"this/is/strange"
"is/strange"
```

How can I get a relative path which I could later combine with my original base path to get the original absolute path? Do I need to use something other than `System.Uri.MakeRelativeUri`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because `MakeRelativeUri` cannot infer if `System32` is a folder or a file with no extension. This will work:

```
new System.Uri("C:\\Windows\\System32\\").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe")).ToString();
```

The same happens with urls. Is `this` a folder or a resource?
This will work though:

```
new System.Uri("http://example.com/this/").MakeRelativeUri(new System.Uri("http://example.com/this/is/strange")).ToString()
```

Comment: Not clear from the documentation that MakeRelativeUri can be applied to any path, not just folders i.e. that the base path can itself be a complete path to a file, not just a path to a folder; this was the source of my confusion.